# Has a supersonic airplane with a truss-braced wing been studied/developed?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing, supersonic

The X-66 truss braced jet is to be transonic. But have any published studies or development programs been done for a supersonic equivalent?

Seems like someone considered it, given that it allows reducing wave drag without grossly increasing weight or wetted area.

Comment: Not sure that wave drag would be lower...